# run REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7" command failed

Tags: teamcity

teamcity version:8.1.3

agent OS: windows 7 64bit

I have a build configuration which has a step only contains the REG QUERY command.

I ran the build configuration and I got an error "ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value." But If I manully remote to agent, run

REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7"

I got following response:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7
    JavaHome    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
    RuntimeLib    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
    MicroVersion    REG_SZ    0

Does anyone know why I get the error if I ran through the teamcity?

Comment: if I change to command to:

REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft"

both teamcity and localmachine works.

Comment: I take it this is a command line build step? Is it a custom script or executable with parameters?